# How do I install xbindkeys on enterprise linux 6? (Centos/RHEL/OEL 6)

Tags: centos, rhel, oracle-linux, xbindkeys

Is there a way to install `xbindkeys` on rhel 6 based distro?

I want to bind keys from my mouse button to run a script.

Comment: just `yum install xbindkeys` should work.

Comment: No package xbindkeys available.
Error: Nothing to do

Answer (score 1):

The package is not contained in the normal repositories but it is in li.nux.ro.

So, enable the repo (and needed EPEL by Fedora):

```
yum install epel-release
rpm -Uvh https://li.nux.ro/download/nux/dextop/el6/x86_64/nux-dextop-release-0-2.el6.nux.noarch.rpm
```

Then you can do

```
yum update
yum install xbindkeys
```

PS: Please note that whenever you enable a new repository it makes the system a little less secure.  However, EPEL and li.nux.ro seem to be well established and probably OK.

Comment: when I  yum update Error: Package: gstreamer-plugins-ugly-0.10.18-4.el6.x86_64 (@rpmfusion-free-updates)
           Requires: libx264.so.120()(64bit)
           Removing: x264-libs-0.120-5.20120303.el6.x86_64 (@rpmfusion-free-updates)
               libx264.so.120()(64bit)
           Updated By: x264-libs-0.142-7.20140728gitaf8e768.el6.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
               Not found

Comment: and Error: Package: vlc-core-2.1.6-2.el6.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
           Requires: live555date(x86-64) = 2012.01.25
           Installed: live555-0-0.37.2012.04.27.el6.x86_64 (@rpmfusion-free-updates)
               live555date(x86-64) = 2012.04.27
           Available: live555-0-0.34.2012.01.25.el6.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
               live555date(x86-64) = 2012.01.25
           Available: live555-0-0.27.2010.04.09.el6.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
               Not found

Comment: then when i yum install xbindkeys : No package xbindkeys available.
Error: Nothing to do

Comment: but when i yum repolist, its there : nux-dextop                                               Nux.Ro RPMs for general desktop use                                                                      1,603

Comment: there's no xbindkeys in that repo http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/dextop/el6/x86_64/